# Way to make content that scrolls under a navigation bar invisible but the bar have transparency

Tags: css

I have no idea how to go about this:

I have a full-screen background image, a navigation bar with 50% transparency fixed to the top, and content below it. How can I have the navigation bar maintain transparency over the background image, and still have scrolling content?

The issue right now is that when I scroll down, the content goes under the navigation bar, and shows through the transparency, which obviously looks awful.

Basically, I want the content of the page to scroll and disappear at the bottom of the navigation bar. I know I could make the navigation bar opaque and use a background image for that too, but I'd rather just have the one full-screen background image.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the contents in a block (div) that has fixed size, say stretch it to the whole page except the size of the navigation bar. Then make that div scrollable with css property `overflow:scroll`

Comment: should I calculate that size with javascript and apply it? Or do I just use 100%?

Comment: `top:30px; bottom:0;` should do it. Where 30px is the size of your navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old but I spent a lot of time looking for the answer and found a good solution so I will post it for anyone else looking for it.

Place the navbar in the element containing the background image and set the navbar's background to inherit. This prevents content from appearing behind the navbar as you scroll down.